# Child born in Russia needs an exit visa?

Tags: visas, russia

My son is born in Russia but we are not Russians I obtain an citizenship of my country and he will have the passport.

Dose he need an exit visa in his passport to leave the country ?

If so what it takes and how long ?

Comment: Which citizenship does your son hold?  Please edit your question to add the appropriate tag (e.g. [tag:indian-citizens], [tag:danish-citizens], etc)

Comment: As far as I can understand the law, **yes** (unless the child's nationality grants him visa waiver for Russia). Child or adult, the only exception to the requirement of exit visas is when the person in question has permanent residency in Russia (вид на жительство).

Comment: No my son just got a US passport and just born in Russia

Answer (score 3):

Unlike US, Russia is not a [Jus soli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli) but a [Jus sanguinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis) state.
That means if at least one of the parents is not a Russian citizen then a child got no rights to the Russian citizenship.
So your son is not a Russian citizen at all.
Also there is no such thing as exit visa in Russia, people (with exception of people working with classified info) can exit Russia freely (but they need an entry visa from the state they're headed into).
For children you should have either both parents present or a written consent of another parent to cross the border (and some evidence you're actually their parents).

Comment: I think there is such thing as an exit visa for people who are residents on work visas.

Comment: @alamar people without Russian citizenship may lose their residency or entry right if they leave depending of circumstances but his doesn't mean they need a visa to exit

Comment: I think that people include implicit "without legal repercussions" to their questions about crossing borders.

Comment: UPD: Actually, from quick googling it seems that exit visa **does not exist anymore**.

Comment: @alamar it's not a legal repercussion, it's just that you have to abide by terms under which you're permitted to enter and stay in the Russian soil. Even then if there is some paperwork to do to exit "cleanly" that paperwork is still not called "visa"

Comment: It was called a visa officially. It went in your passport.